# Possible method/function to list out every variation of multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is it possible to list out every single variation possible with some kind of filtering or mapping method?
I'm using a small array/sample size, but assume the sizes vary. Focusing on **3 arrays** and ***listing out each variation.***

Thank you,

```
// pseudo-code!

var breakfast = ["eggs", "cereal" , "muffin"];
var lunch = ["soup", "burrito"];
var dinner =["salad", "steak", "ice cream"];



// outputs

eggs,soup,salad
eggs,soup,steak
eggs,soup,ice cream
eggs,burrito,salad
eggs,burrito,steak
...etc....
```

Comment: Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. *(Not my downvote)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this a while back in `php`, while not `javascript`, perhaps you can adjust for what you need ...

https://gist.github.com/farinspace/1126042

Comment: It was in PHP, but it does work, I was able to list out all possible variations...100k to be exact! Thank you for the script!